# RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction

Tags: swift, realm

I've encountered following error when I've complied following code:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call
>   beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

```
for outlet in brand.outlets! {
    let outl = OutletListRealm()
    outl.outletId = outlet.id
    outl.outletName = outlet.name!
    outl.brand = brand.id
    try! self.realm.write {
        self.realm.add(outl)
    }

    for override in outlet.override! {
        let overRide = OverRideObjectRealm()
        overRide.id = override.id
        overRide.name = override.name!
        overRide.brand = brand.name!
        overRide.outlet = outlet.name!
        outl.brand = brand.id
        try! self.realm.write {
            self.realm.add(overRide)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `outl.brand = brand.id` in `for override` should not be there

Comment: @EpicPandaForce damn, my careless mistake. Please write as answer? I'll mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

You need to do all thing in `realm.write`
Just update your code as follows.

See this: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#writes

```
for outlet in brand.outlets! {
        let outl = OutletListRealm()
        try! self.realm.write {
            outl.outletId = outlet.id
            outl.outletName = outlet.name!
            outl.brand = brand.id
            self.realm.add(outl)
        }

        for override in outlet.override! {
            let overRide = OverRideObjectRealm()
            try! self.realm.write {
                overRide.id = override.id
                overRide.name = override.name!
                overRide.brand = brand.name!
                overRide.outlet = outlet.name!
                self.realm.add(overRide)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have a question, whats the proper way to fetch saved objects. As per your answer it address only save and delete thats why i asked