# How to edit realm object and save editing?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have 2 Controllers: `TableViewController` and ViewController. `TableViewController` is responsible for displaying all data, View Controller is responsible for creating new data. 
Now I want to make it possible to edit the current data also in `ViewController`. When we click on data, we need to switch to the `ViewController` and replace all default values with the current values. When we change and click save, we go back to `TableViewController`, where we already see the change.

```
class OperationsViewController: UITableViewController {

// MARK: - Stored Properties
var transactions: Results<Transaction>!
var sections = [(date: Date, items: Results<Transaction>)]()

// MARK: - UITableViewController Methods
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    transactions = realm.objects(Transaction.self)
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super .viewWillAppear(animated)
    assembleGroupedTransactions()
    tableView.reloadData()
  }
}

// MARK: - Navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        let section = sections[indexPath.section]
        let item = section.items[indexPath.row]
        print(item)
        if segue.identifier == "editOrDeleteOperationCell" {
            let addTableViewController = segue.destination as! AddTableViewController
            addTableViewController.defaultTransaction = item
        }
    }
  }
}

// MARK: - User Interface
extension OperationsViewController {

@discardableResult private func assembleGroupedTransactions() -> Array<Any> {
    // fetch all Items sorted by date
    let results = realm.objects(Transaction.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: false)

    sections = results
        .map { item in
            // get start of a day
            return Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: item.date)
        }
        .reduce([]) { dates, date in
            // unique sorted array of dates
            return dates.last == date ? dates : dates + [date]
        }
        .compactMap { startDate -> (date: Date, items: Results<Transaction>) in
            // create the end of current day
            let endDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: startDate)!
            // filter sorted results by a predicate matching current day
            let items = results.filter("(date >= %@) AND (date < %@)", startDate, endDate)
            // return a section only if current day is non-empty
            return (date: startDate, items: items)
    }
    return sections
}
```

But when I trying to send current data to next `ViewController` I get error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'
>
> ---

I guess that I have problem with `Category`. Look on my model:

```
class Transaction: Object {

@objc dynamic var controlStatus = 0

@objc dynamic private var privateCategory: String = Category.consumption.rawValue
var category: Category {
    get { return Category(rawValue: privateCategory)! }
    set { privateCategory = newValue.rawValue }
}

@objc dynamic var amount = "0"
@objc dynamic var date = Date()
@objc dynamic var note = ""
}
```

`controlStatus` needs for monitors the status of the transaction that will be needed in the future. Where 0 is the expense, 1 is the income.
The big problem I suppose is that I created categories by `enum`. 
I need to change the arrays with categories depending on the `controlStatus`.
Now is this my model of Category:

```
indirect enum Category: String {
case income = "+"
case consumption = "-"

case salary = "salary"
case billingInterest = "billingInterest"
case partTimeJob = "partTimeJob"

etc.
}

extension Category: RawRepresentable {
typealias RawValue = String

init?(rawValue: RawValue) {
    switch rawValue {
    case "+": self = .income
    case "-": self = .consumption

    case "salary": self = .salary
    case "billingInterest": self = .billingInterest
    case "partTimeJob: self = .partTimeJob
    case "pleasantFinds": self = .pleasantFinds
    case "debtRepayment": self = .debtRepayment

    case "noCategories": self = .noCategories
    case "food": self = .food

    etc. 

    default:
        return nil
    }
}

var rawValue: RawValue {
    switch self {
    case .salary:
        return "salary"
    case .billingInterest:
        return "billingInterest"
    case .partTimeJob:
        return "partTimeJob"
    case .pleasantFinds:
        return "pleasantFinds"
    case .debtRepayment:
        return "debtRepayment"

    case .noCategories:
        return "noCategories"
    case .food:
        return "food"
    case .cafesAndRestaurants:
        return "cafesAndRestaurants"
    etc.
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `realm.write { ... }`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50113512/rlmexception-reason-attempting-to-modify-object-outside-of-a-write-transacti)

Comment: @vpoltave No, these are different questions.

Comment: So when exactly is the exception thrown: can you use the stack trace to show the line that causes it. I can't see any problems in this code. You're using `addTableViewController.defaultTransaction = item` to pass the item to the second VC which is fine, but this is now uneditable in the VC outside of `realm.write` block. I suspect the crash is caused by some editing code that isn't included above - what other code is in `AddTableViewController`? It may be in `viewDidLoad` or you may edit the `defaultTransaction` somewhere else - which you can't do. How is `editData` called?

Comment: @ChrisShaw I begin to guess what the problem may be. When I comment out the `categories`, the `item` is passed. Most likely I have a problem with the transfer `Category`. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Possibly, but you'll need to show more as I've asked.

Comment: @ChrisShaw Maybe I should to create a new question?

Comment: Just add the extra information to this question.

Comment: @ChrisShaw Look on edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193442/discussion-between-chris-shaw-and-mikhail-tseitlin).

Answer (score 2):

You need to enclose your realm write transactions in write block

`try realm.write({ () -> Void in
     realm.add(object, update: true)
 })`

Comment: Do you mean, I should use this method when I press "save" in `ViewController`?

Comment: yes. while saving, do it in this block. check realm docs for examples

Comment: But how to pass current Data from `TableViewController` to `ViewController`?

Comment: You can use any pattern to achieve that based on the architecture of your app. There is delegate pattern using callbacks, then there is observer pattern using notifications, etc.

Comment: You probably didn't understand me that way. I don't know how to start editing when I click on currentData.

Answer (score 1):

From Realm [doc](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects)

```
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(myDog)
}
```